# How to replace the placeholders with the values coming from an array in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a text coming from jSON like below. I would like to replace **[currency:a]** with **USD** and **[currency:b]** with **50M** and so on. Please note this should be the dynamic, I mean the Placeholders may increase. Can anyone help how to do this in Angular 6.

```json
{
"Text":"Not to exceed [currency:a][amount:b] in respect of General Aviation liability primary lines </li><li>not to exceed [currency:c][amount:d] in respect of Airline Liability,[currency:e][amount:f]"
"placeHolderValues": {
    "a": " 'USD'",
    "b": " '50M'",
    "c": " 'GBP'",
    "d": " '100M'",
    "e": " 'HKD'",
    "f": " '150M'",
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably go with a `pipe` which takes in the variables and returns the whole string, something like:

```
transform(currencies: string[], amounts: number[]): string {
  return `not to exceed ${currencies[0]}${amounts[0]} in respect of Airline Liability,${currencies[1]}${amounts[1]}`;
}
```

You should be able to make it general so that it accepts more values and more strings to replace, just add more parameters.

Then in your template you can use the pipe like:

```
<input type="text" [placeholder]="'base string' | addCurrencies" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. this is not the Input. I need to render this in the UI. the final Outcome should be like

Comment: Thanks for the response. My output should come like below,    Not to exceed USD 50M in respect of General Aviation liability primary lines </li><li>not to exceed GBP 100M in respect of Airline Liability,HKD 150M .  Can you let me know how we can replace them while rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Make a getter and bind it to `[placeholder]`. That would work.

```ts
get text() {
  const currency = this.currency.placeHolderValues
  return `Not to exceed ${currency.a}${currency.b} in respect of General Aviation liability primary lines not to exceed ${currency.c}${currency.d} in respect of Airline Liability,${currency.e}${currency.f}`
}
```

```html
<input [placeholder]="text" style="width: 100%">
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x8u8bm

Comment: Thanks for the response. My output should come like below,    Not to exceed USD 50M in respect of General Aviation liability primary lines </li><li>not to exceed GBP 100M in respect of Airline Liability,HKD 150M .  Can you let me know how we can replace them while rendering.

Comment: It could be done with getter. I've updated stackblitz.

Comment: Hi I couldnot see any update in stackbliz.. Can you please share the latest. As mentioned the text needs to be rendered with the replaced values. Thanks for the help

Comment: Forgot to save it. Updated again.

Comment: thank you for the update I can see it now.Here in the getter, we need to write the entire string. For me the text will be dynamic and never know the which  text will come. SO I need to have  a function which accepts Text and placeHolderValues as an input and return the string with the correct values. Thanks for the help.

Comment: any help on this one pls.